# Xamarin Forms applying Behaviors to StackLayout using Prism

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, prism

I am trying to bind two labels with the date on the click of the StackLayout.  The stacklayout has three elements, a label to display the date, another label to display the Month and Year, and the third element is a datepicker with the visiblity set to false.

My XAML

```
<StackLayout>
     <Label Text="End Date" Style="{StaticResource H2Style}"  HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
     <Label Text="26" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
     <Label Text="Mar 2017" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
     <DatePicker x:Name="endDatePicker" IsVisible="false" />
     <StackLayout.Behaviors>
        <b:EventToCommandBehavior EventName="DateTapped" 
            Command="{Binding DatePickerCommand}"
            CommandParameter= "{x:Reference endDatePicker}" />
     </StackLayout.Behaviors>
</StackLayout>
```

I would like to show the datepicker dialog on the click of the stackLayout.

My ViewModel

```
public class MyViewModel : BindableBase
{
    public DelegateCommand<Object> DatePickerCommand { get; set; }
    public MyViewModel()
    {
        DatePickerCommand = new DelegateCommand<Object>(DateTapped);

    }

    private void DateTapped(Object obj)
    {
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
        {
            if (endDatePicker.IsFocused)
                endDatePicker.Unfocus();
            endDatePicker.Focus();
        });
    }
}
```

But I get the following error:

```
Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSInternalInconsistencyException 
Reason: Application windows are expected to have a root view 
controller at the end of application launch
Native stack trace:
0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104b7bb0b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010f757141 objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104b7fcf2 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 98
3   Foundation                          0x0000000105732536 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 193
4   UIKit                               0x0000000109adac46 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 3343
5   UIKit                               0x0000000109ad77f3 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 182
6   FrontBoardServices                  0x000000011246f5f6 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 24
7   FrontBoardServices                  0x000000011246f46d -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 186
8   FrontBoardServices                  0x000000011246f7f6 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 45
9   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104b21c01 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
10  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104b070cf __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 527
11  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104b065ff __CFRunLoopRun + 911
12  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104b06016 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 406
13  UIKit                               0x0000000109ad608f -[UIApplication _run] + 468
14  UIKit                               0x0000000109adc134 UIApplicationMain + 159
15  ???                                 0x00000001282fcd94 0x0 + 4969188756
16  ???                                 0x00000001282fc9dd 0x0 + 4969187805
```

I will appreciate if someone can help me with this

Comment: you might want to catch the real exception -
 https://stackoverflow.com/q/43556274/1155650

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue might be an unhandled exception somewhere in any of the threads. 
You might want to catch the real exception by following this - [Forms with Prism: Application windows are expected to have a root VC](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43556274/1155650)

Instead of trying to set focus on an invisible control which mostly be unexpected behaviour, why not use Date picker as a dialog from [ACR User Dialogs for Xamarin and Windows](https://github.com/aritchie/userdialogs)

Comment: Your comment and answer helped me to fix the problem. I left it with the same way as it is now (datepicker hidden). WIll check how it works and would make an appropriate action. For anyone else who has similar issues, I strongly recommend to check the stackoverflow link the comment, on how to expose the real error.  In my case, it was the event name, event name should be something that the control or view supports. I added Tag gesture and it works